# Use object method in asp.net MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, extension-methods

A month or two ago when I started doing asp.net MVC work I remember reading that it is not recommended to call object methods like the following in the view:

```
<%: Html.ListBoxFor( m => Model.SelectedId, Model.SelectItems.ToSelectList() ) %>
```

That above is just an example, not a direct line of code I am using.  I am using extension methods to turn my enumerables into ListBox binding-ready IEnumerable collections. I know there was a concern that someone had raised in an article about this, but I cannot remember what it was.  I am not actually coding it this was at the moment, but the way I am doing it is becoming a burden.  I am writing extension methods to convert all of my IEnumerable objects into both SelectListItem collections and now a MultiSelectList object.  So my view models are becoming bloated with "potential" ways of displaying the data.  Instead of their just being an enumerable of available options, I am tracking 4 new pieces of data: SelectListItem collection, SelectListValue object, MultiSelectList control, MultiSelectListValues collection.

I am not opposed to keep going about this, but I would like to remember why it was recommend not to call the extension method on the View if I'm using strongly-typed full/partial views.  I tried to find that article and others like it but I could not.  I wish my memory was better than this, but hopefully someone out there knows this offhand and would be willing to share it with me!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea your talking about is based on a principal that the view in MVC should be as simple as possible. Because it is the most difficult to test unnecessary bloat should be avoided.
Your example line could be paired down a few different ways. You could try writing an extension that takes the enumeration from your model and converts it to a select list that can be fed into a listbox, or you can change the model's property to return an enumeration of list items. The later is my preferred method. The model exists to organize the data to be consumed by the view so theres no reason to have it output data that cannot be consumed by the view directly. Either one of these methods would take complexity out of the view and place it somewhere that is easier to unit test.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I had a feeling it was just a "philosophical" reason but I couldn't remember.  I am currently handling it all in the controller and creating new entries in the model for each method that could possibly be needed. I have an extension method to convert the enumerable and I am calling that while populating the model before sending it anywhere.  As it seemed easier to just call the extension in the view, I wanted to remember why my brain kept yelling at me not to do so.  Thanks for the reminder! Too much too fast... hard to keep it all straight sometimes haha.